# How to set entire row vector to be 0 if the condition satisfied (R)

Tags: r

I want to compute M such that if there is element in the matrix m is less than 3, the entire row will be set to 0, and M will have the same dimension as m. I'm not sure what went wrong with the code.

```
x <-seq(5,10)
y <-seq(1,5)
z <- seq(10,15)
m <- cbind(x,y,z)
as.matrix(m)

M <- matrix(NA, 6,3)


for (i in 1:6) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
  M[i,j] <- ifelse(m[i,j] <3, m[i,]==0, m[i,j])
  
}
}
M
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    0   10
[2,]    6    0   11
[3,]    7    3   12
[4,]    8    4   13
[5,]    9    5   14
[6,]   10    0   15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` to create a logical vector and assign those rows having any value less than 3 to 0

```
M <- m
M[rowSums(m < 3) > 0,] <- 0
```

-output

```
M
#     x y  z
#[1,] 0 0  0
#[2,] 0 0  0
#[3,] 7 3 12
#[4,] 8 4 13
#[5,] 9 5 14
#[6,] 0 0  0
```